# ListView.builder and Hive database, misaligned index when deleted an entry

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-hive

I have a listView.builder building a list for me using information from Hive database.
If I create 3 entries (0, 1, 2), the builder will be like this (0,1,2). If Idelete the (1) hive database keys become this (0,2), but the index generated by the listviewBuilder becomes this (0,1). misaligning the data.

Each entry is an instance of a Person object, just so you guys know

What is the solution? There is a function to recreate the Keys without holes?

[image]
Created DB and ListView Builder

[image]
Deleted the second card

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: peopleList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(
                  (Icons.person),
                  color: Colors.teal,
                ),
                title: Text(
                    " ${peopleList[index].name} (${peopleList[index].vehicleType} ${peopleList[index].partieRole} ) ${isDriver(index)}"),
                subtitle: Text(
                    'Injured: ${parseBool(peopleList[index].isInjured)}, transported to hospital: ${parseBool(peopleList[index].isTransported)} ${isCitated(index)} '),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: buildPopMenu(index, peopleList),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  print(index);
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
```

the floating button creates showDialog that adds an object to the Hive db

box.add(Person);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i understand you , you need first to give each item a keyValue based on the last item in your HiveBox and when you want to delete or update some items you will do that based on your keyValue and not based on the index of your ListViewBuilder

this code for adding items

```
void addNewOrder(NewOrder order) {
  final ordersBox = Hive.box('order');
  var lengthBox = Hive.box('order').values;
  if (lengthBox.isEmpty) {
    ordersBox.put(1, order);
    print('the box is empty');
  } else {
    lengthBox.forEach((item) => allorder.add(item.key));
    int lastElement = allorder.last;
    int newElement = lastElement + 1;
    ordersBox.put(newElement, order);
    allorder.clear();
  }
}
```

and this code is for retrieving the order of items

```
List<int> productkey = [];
List<dynamic> items = [];

items = Hive.box('order').values.toList();

items.forEach((item) {
       productkey.add(item.key);
});
```

and this line is for deleting put it in the onPressed

```
Hive.box('order').delete(productkey[index]);
```

i hope i was clear

Comment: I didn't understand it very well.
How can I use this on ListView?Builder? since it generates its index?

Comment: Yes, there are two types of indexes, the index of the HiveBox and the index of the listViewBuilder , so in the first use the list and hiveBox are the same .
but when you delete with the deleteAt(index)  the function get the index of the list and use it to delete the element in the HiveBox that has the same index as the list so it will have an overlap 

that's why it's better to manage the indexes by yourself and use the function delete() as I showed you above insted of deleteAt()

Comment: my delete function is actually like this // peopleList[index].delete();
I'm using the extended method from the hive object

Comment: I solved the problem, but I still want to learn the correct way.
What I did is I wrapped the entry with a visible widget and I hid it instead of deleting the entry. this way the "deleted" are still there they are just being ignored. keeping both index/keys sincronized